# django how to create hashed password using create_user() method

Tags: python, django

I have this problem for a month.

I'm using `abstractbasemodel` and `basemanagerto` to create a login and signup API using rest framework.

However, when I create a user password, it is saved as raw data since I use `set_password()` method and custom model manager confuses me...

This is my code :

```
class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):    
    class Meta:
        model        = UserProfile
        fields       = ('id' ,'email' ,'name' ,'password')
        extra_kwargs = {
            'password':{
                'write_only':'True',
                'style': {'input_type': 'password'}
            }
        } 

        def create(self, validated_data):
            user = UserProfile.people.create_user(
                email = validated_data['email'],
                name  = validated_data['name'],
                password = validated_data['password']
            )

class UserProfileViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = serializers.UserProfileSerializer
    queryset = models.UserProfile.people.all()
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication, )
    permission_classes     = (UpdateOwnProfile, )
    filter_backends        = (SearchFilter, )
    search_fields          = ('name', 'email')


class UserLoginApiView(ObtainAuthToken):
    renderer_classes = api_settings.DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES

class UserProfileManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, name, password=None):
        print("user model manager")
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('User Must Have an Email Address')
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, name=name )
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, name, password):
        user = self.create_user(email, name, password)
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.is_staff     = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

class UserProfile(AbstractBaseUser,PermissionsMixin):
    email           =         models.EmailField(max_length=255,unique=True)
    name            = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    is_active       = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff        = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    people = UserProfileManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD  = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['name']

    def get_full_name(self):
        return self.name

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.name

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

class Profile(models.Model):
    user         =     models.OneToOneField(UserProfile,on_delete=models.CASCADE,relat    ed_name="Profile")
    location     =     models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True,null=True)
    bio          =     models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True,null=True)
    creationDate = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    follower     =     models.ManyToManyField(UserProfile,related_name="Following",blank=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name='Profile'
        verbose_name_plural='Profiles'
```

I also defined auth user model in settings :

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL='profiles.UserProfile'
```

to make sure Django uses my custom user model.

I don't know whats wrong as there is no error and only superusers that are created in terminal using `manage.py` are saved with hashed password.

Users which are created with my viewsets are saved with raw password.

First, I named the model manager "objects" and now, its people but the create user method wont run at all.

Comment: UserProfileSerializer's create function should return the newly created instance, can you add `return user` to the create function block

Answer (score 1):

You can use django's built in hasher to create hashed password. It can be applied in `.create` method. First import `from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password` and then modify `.create()` method,

```
    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = UserProfile.people.create_user(
            email = validated_data['email'],
            name  = validated_data['name'],
            password = make_password(validated_data['password']) # here
        )
        return user
```

**Or**

if you don't override the `.create()` method then add the following `validate_password` method in serializer,
The validate_password is ran, everytime a new object has to be created

```
class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):    
    class Meta:
        model        = UserProfile
        fields       = ('id' ,'email' ,'name' ,'password')
        extra_kwargs = {
            'password':{
                'write_only':'True',
                'style': {'input_type': 'password'}
            }
        } 
    def validate_password(self, value: str) -> str:
        return make_password(value)
```

Comment: indent error at the last two line |
the validate_password function must be under UserProfileSerializer not under class